# Help identify this unknown seedling please

Tags: identification, seedlings

I'm not familiar with this plant and want to know so i can decide if it lives or not (mostly based on safety of my dogs) i was thinking hibiscus but someone else suggested a type of mulberry, it gets moderate shade at different times of the day and its surviving 116 degrees in gravel landscaping..i water it when i water the hibiscus its in between (every other day) it grew wild either wind or bird poop probably
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrDTf.jpg)!
the older it gets it looks similar to a strawberry but not quite

Comment: You can try plant identification apps like Plantsnap and iNaturalist.